# Following a custom path in TweenJs

Tags: javascript, animation, tween

i'm trying to design a simple animation with TweenJs.. 
Lets consider two people playing throwing ball. I've managed to move the ball in a linear path. But it has to seem realistic. Ball should follow a curvy path like there is gravity.. How can i define "checkpoints" in the path? Or should i change my tactic to achive that goal?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

The recently released TweenJS (Version 0.4.0, Feb 12, 2013) contains a MotionGuidePlugin. The usage is pretty simple:

```
// Using a Motion Guide
createjs.Tween.get(target).to({guide:{ path:[0,0, 0,200,200,200, 200,0,0,0] }},7000);
// Visualizing the line
graphics.moveTo(0,0).curveTo(0,200,200,200).curveTo(200,0,0,0);
```

Here is a quick fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/qEYD4/1/

More info in the docs.
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/classes/MotionGuidePlugin.html